# Ubuntu: setup Windows networking without CLI?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, networking

I know how to setup my Ubuntu system for integration with a Windows Network through the CLI but, as an experiment, I tried doing the same configuration through the **default** installation... interesting, I wasn't able to find a Network Configuration tool.

So the question is: how does one setup an Ubuntu machine to integrate with a Windows Network **without** resorting to CLI hackery ?

**Updated**: a reason I am asking this question: how do "non-geeks" (or "CLI-paranoid") get to configure their Ubuntu/Linux machines ??

**Update2**: More specifically, how can I configure something like "workgroup name" without resorting to CLI?

Comment: GUI hackery is just like CLI hackery, except more hand-holdy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neglect to mention exactly what you need to accomplish this "Windows Networking integration" beyond specifying a workgroup.

For secure, password-protected shares, and to specify a particular workgroup, you need to configure your `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

You can use [swat](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/swat) ([Samba Web Administration Tool](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/SWAT.html), available in Karmic's `universe` repository); it's an older package but should still work.  Typically, once SWAT is installed and running, you use it by browsing to `http://localhost:901/`.

You can also use [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/); install it via the [.deb package](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.490_all.deb) on [the Webmin download page](http://www.webmin.com/download.html).  Have a look at the [Webmin Samba HOW-TO](http://www.webmin.com/samba-howto.html) for specifics.  Either of these tools will provide web-based configuration for Samba; Webmin configures many other services as well.

Read through Ubuntu's [Setting Up Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba) page for more info.  You can configure very simple shares directly in Gnome, as matpol's answer suggests -- use Gnome's "Places" menu to connect to shares from other computers.  You can also *create* shares by browsing to them in the filemanager and selecting "Share Folder" in the right-click menu.  If you don't have the Samba server installed, you'll get a popup that tells you "Sharing services are not installed".  Select the SMB option, deselect NFS, and then click "Install Services".  This will install the [samba](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/samba) and [smbfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/smbfs) packages for you, and then create a basic, browsable, public share on the folder you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

On one of the menus in gnome the second one along 'Places' I think it's called you can connect to network stuff whether it be a samba share or a ftp connection.

A better explanation here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba#Browsing%20SMB%20shares

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need network configuration! Just install Samba and you should see network shares in your Network folder immediately. You might need to change the default workgroup name, however. Access the network folder by clicking Network on the left side of your file manager window in Oneiric.